# Ubuntu не читает внешний HDD

Tags: ubuntu, железо, hdd, recovery, samsung

Всех приветствую :D
На работе дали пару стареньких HDD, посмотреть и попытаться восстановить их, если это возможно.
Внешняя рабочая докстанция для чтения жёстких дисков имеется и я решил попробовать.

Сам диск старенький. Samsung HD160JJ на 160GB.
При запуске крутится, работает нормально, без лишних звуков, скрипов, скрежета.

**fdisk -l** не видит его.

**ls -l /dev | grep -E 'sd|hd'** видит его через пару минут, как я его подключаю.

Вот его вывод:

```
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,     1 чэр  6 09:34 sda1
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,     2 чэр  6 09:34 sda2
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,     3 чэр  6 09:34 sda3
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,    16 чэр  6 09:34 sdb
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,    17 чэр  6 09:34 sdb1
brw-rw----  1 root disk        8,    32 чэр  6 09:38 sdc
```

Определяется он как **sdc**.

**lsblk** его не видит

Вывод из ядра следующий
**sudo dmesg | grep sdc**

```
[ 2294.043691] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 2329.870664] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2329.870668] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2329.870673] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2329.870675] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2329.870682] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2329.870683] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 2329.870687] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 2329.870689] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 2329.870692] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 2329.870695] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2329.914817] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2329.914821] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2329.914825] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2329.914826] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2329.914834] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2339.132106] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 2398.511391] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2398.511408] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2398.511420] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 2398.511872] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2398.511882] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2398.511892] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 2398.512420] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2398.512427] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 2398.512711] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 2398.512814] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 2398.512823] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2398.512963] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[ 2398.567619] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unit Not Ready
[ 2398.567631] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2398.567642] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 2398.568101] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2398.568115] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2398.568126] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 2398.568448] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2398.568453] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2398.568461] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 2398.569516] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2700.692769] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 2801.767158] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2801.767173] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2801.767196] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2801.767203] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2801.767230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2801.767237] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 2801.767252] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 2801.767258] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 2801.767269] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 2801.767281] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2801.815686] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2801.815698] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2801.815714] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2801.815719] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 2801.815748] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 3237.547980] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 3349.905311] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3349.905325] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 3349.905330] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 3355.904940] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3355.904954] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 3355.904960] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 3355.905417] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 3355.905423] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 3361.905567] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 3363.904907] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 3363.904912] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3363.905052] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[ 3365.954414] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 3466.291399] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3466.291412] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 3466.291423] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 3466.291890] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3466.291896] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 3466.291905] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 3466.293072] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 4072.968510] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 4185.300917] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4185.300931] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 4185.300937] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 4191.300488] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4191.300502] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 4191.300507] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 4191.301039] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 4191.301045] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 4197.300412] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 4199.300379] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 4199.300396] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4199.300663] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[ 4199.350455] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 4301.685464] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4301.685492] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4301.685503] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4301.685955] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4301.685970] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4301.685979] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4301.687201] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Что делать дальше - пока что без понятия.

Вопрос в том, *как его возможно реанимировать, и если нет - почему*?

Comment: Скорее тут вопрос должен быть ¿Зачем его реанимировать? Если нужно восстановить данные - несите специалистам. Иначе несите на помойку.

Comment: @user7860670 ну я вообще хочу научиться с этим работать. Интерес и энтузиазм.
А так, хочется просто привести его в более-менее живое работоспособное состояние, и посмотреть, как долго он проработает. Возможно этот вопрос кому-нибудь поможет в будущем при гуглении :)

Comment: `Внешняя рабочая докстанция` дальше не читал. Если тебе работоспосоность поверхности проверить - `mhdd`, если файлы восстановить - `ddrescue+easy recovery\r-studio`. Если всё хуже - только узкопрофильные спецы как писали выше.